# PHP and Elasticsearch include score/relevance in returned object

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, ongr

So I'm using PHP Symfony and the Ongr-Elasticsearch bundle, to query my documents and return matching objects. The results seem to be sorted by relevance/score, but the actual relevance/score isn't included in the objects themselves.

Is this possible to do? I'd like to include the score in what I send to the frontend to be able to do stuff with it.

Code:

```
$search = $this->esRepository->createSearch();
$search->setSize(30);
$queryFields = array(....);
$queryStringQuery = new QueryStringQuery($queryString, ["fields" => $queryFields]);
$search->addQuery($queryStringQuery);
$esResults = $this->esRepository->execute($search, Repository::RESULTS_ARRAY);
```

Comment: Take a look at this Bundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle. Handles everything you want, simple indexing and Querying.

Answer (score 2):

When you are executing query with `Repository::RESULTS_ARRAY` it only returns _source from hits. What you want to use is `Repository::RESULTS_RAW_ITERATOR` ant it will return whole hit which will include _score.